# Proof that the Wiener process is non-differentiable

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-processes

I'm working through a proof showing that the Wiener process is non differentiable given as follows
[image]

I am not quite sure where the 2 in front of the integral stems from though. Any help would be highyly appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Physics SE! Please don't post formulae as screenshots or plain text, but use MathJax instead. MathJax is easy for people on all devices to read, and can show up clearer on different screen sizes and resolutions. I've edited it here as an example. Look at [this Math SE meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick tutorial.

Comment: Hi Chair,

Thanks for the heads up - I'll keep that in mind :-)

Comment: I see you've left a 'thanks' comment under LonelyProf's answer. If that answer helped you enough, it's a better idea to mark it as accepted (I think you'll see a grey tick mark or something next to that answer). "thank-you" comments are usually deleted here because they're considered to be noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine that it is because the distribution of $\Delta B$ ranges from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ and we are seeking values of $|\Delta B| > A\Delta t$. The integral is symmetric, so the range is changed to just cover the positive interval, and the result is doubled.